# Log in page which reads details from XML file java

Tags: java, file-io, authentication, xml-parsing

I have created a basic log in page in Java that allows a user to log in successfully, however I have hard coded the username and password into the program. I would like to extend the program so it can accept multiple users from the XML File, as hard coding the details will be inefficient. This is the chunk of code that validates the log in details.

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    if(username.getText().length()==0||password.getText().length()==0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Mistake");


    } else if (username.getText().trim().equals("admin")&& password.getText().equals("hello")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success)); 

    }else {


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }           
}
```

This code only allows admin to log in as it is hard coded into the program.

Would the best solution to be to create a new class that reads the XML file and then create a object in the code above with the parameters username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your users/passwords in an xml file will be an improvement over your actual code.

However, cipher `(MD5?)` the passwords to avoid having files in your disk whith pwds in plain text!

So you need to cipher also the passwords the users are introducing and then compare the cyphered codes, not the raw ones.

Typically this info is stored in an XML file or preferably in a database (which is also protected by its own access security policy)